# Javascript game with css position

Tags: javascript, css, position

I am trying to make a very simple helicopter game in javascript and I'm currently using css positions to move the objects. but I wanted to know if there was a better/other method for moving objects (divs) when a user is pressing a button

here's a code i've got so far..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Game 2 helicopter</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function num(x){
  return parseInt(x.replace(/([^0-9]+)/g,''));  
}

function getPos(x, y){    
  var inum=Math.floor(Math.random()*(y+1-x)) + x;
  inum=inum;
  return inum; 
}

function setTop(x,y){ x.style.top = y+'px'; }
function setBot(x,y){ x.style.bottom = y+'px'; }
function setLeft(x,y){ x.style.left = y+'px'; }
function setRight(x,y){ x.style.right = y+'px'; }

function getTop(x){ return num(x.style.top); }
function getBot(x){ return num(x.style.bottom); }
function getLeft(x){ return num(x.style.left); }
function getRight(x){ return num(x.style.right); }

function moveLeft(x,y){
  var heli = document.getElementById('heli');   
  var obj = document.getElementById('obj');  
  var poss = [20,120,350,400];
  var r_pos = getPos(1,4);
  var rand_pos = poss[r_pos];
  xleft = getLeft(x)-y;
  if(xleft>0){
   xleft=xleft;
  }
  else{
   xleft=800;
  setTop(x,rand_pos);
  }  
  setLeft(x,xleft);
  setTimeout(function(){moveLeft(x,y)},10);
  checkGame(heli,obj);
}
var heli;
var obj;

function checkGame(x,y){
 var obj_right = getLeft(x) + 100;
 var yt = getTop(y);
 var yb = (getTop(y)+100);
   if(getTop(x) >= yt && getTop(x) <= yb && obj_right==getLeft(y)){
     endGame();
   }
}

function func(){
  var x = document.getElementById('heli');
  var y = document.getElementById('obj');
  alert(getTop(x)+' '+getTop(y)+' '+(getTop(y)+200));
}

function startGame(e){
  document.getElementById('park').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('newgame').style.display='none';
  heli = document.getElementById('heli');
  obj = document.getElementById('obj');
  hp = heli.style.top;
  op = obj.style.top;
  setTop(heli,20);
  setLeft(heli,20);

  setLeft(obj,800);
  setTop(obj,20);
  moveLeft(obj,5);    
}

function newGameLoad(){
  document.getElementById('park').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('newgame').style.display='block';
}

function gamePos(e){
  heli = document.getElementById('heli');
  obj = document.getElementById('obj');
  var keynum;
  var keychar;
  var numcheck;

  if(window.event){ // IE
    keynum = e.keyCode;
  }
  else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    keynum = e.which;
  }

  keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum); // up=38 down=40 left=37 right=39
  /*if(keynum==37){ //left
    tl=tl-20;
    db.style.left = tl + 'px';
  }

  if(keynum==39){ //right
    //stopPos();
    tl=tl+20;
    db.style.left = tl + 'px';
  }*/

  curb = getTop(heli);

  if(keynum==38){ //top
    setTop(heli,curb-10);
    //alert(curb+10);
  }

  if(keynum==40){ //bottom
    setTop(heli,curb+10);
    //alert(curb-10);
  }
}

function endGame(){
  clearTimeout();
  newGameLoad();
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .play{position:absolute;color:#fff;}  #heli{background:url(http://classroomclipart.com/images/gallery/Clipart/Transportation/Helicopter/TN_00-helicopter2.jpg);width:150px;height:59px;}
  #obj{background:red;width:20px;height:200px;}
  .park{height:550px;border:5px solid brown;border-left:none;border-right:none;}
  #newgame{display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame();" onkeydown="gamePos(event);">
  <div class="park" id="park">
    <div id="heli" class="play"></div>
    <div id="obj" class="play"></div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="newgame" style="position:absolute;top:25%;left:25%;" onclick="startGame();" value="New Game" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doing what? A more efficient moving script, or a better way than CSS?

Comment: more efficent script, if possible. and I also want to know if the way i'm using isn't reccomended..

Answer (score 3):

Some general comments:

1. `parseInt()` already ignores trailing non-numerics, so there's no need for your `num()` function. If there were, you could write that regex more simply as `/\D+/g`.
2. If speed is critical, a marginally faster way to floor a number is `x<<0`.
3. All of `getPos` should just be: `return Math.floor(...)+x;`. I have no idea why you declare and set a variable, set it to itself, and then return it.
4. Instead of re-getting the `heli` and `obj` items each call to `moveLeft()`, you should set them once (after the document as loaded) and let `moveLeft()` be a closure that references them. Same with `poss`.
5. You forgot to `var` your `xleft` variable, which makes it a global.
6. You have `if (xleft>0){ xleft=xleft; }`. This doesn't do anything.
7. You can declare multiple variables on the same line, e.g. `var heli, obj;`
8. Instead of using `alert` for debugging, use `console.log` (or better yet, actual breakpoints and stepping through your code). You will find your life  far, far easier. Look up Developer Tools for Safari/Chrome or Firebug for Firefox.
9. There are more global variables such as `hp` and `op`.
10. You should look into a library like `jQuery` which will make your code easier to develop. For example, you don't have to do the browser-specific tests for events, as it normalizes them.
11. Use a `switch()` statement to process your keycodes instead of multiple `if` statements.
12. Remove the `onload` and `onkeydown` handlers from your body, and instead register them programmatically from your script.
13. Remove the `style` attribute from your HTML, and put it in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions man. I will definatley apply them to the script. one thing though: I do use jquery on almost everything I work on, but I thought it wouldn't be neccessary on this

Comment: @nesb125505 Since you appear to be new to Stack Overflow, know that you should "vote up" (up arrow) any answers that have helped you, and "accept" (checkmark) the answer (if any) that you feel has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes do not use a Timer to poll if a event has happened. Use javascript's addEventListener or jQuery's event functions.I would use recommend jQuery as it would probably make writing other parts of your code faster as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. If you know you don't need more than (say) 30fps, but the key event fires more frequently than this, it makes more sense to use a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` and do super lightweight processing of events between.